# How to get value from HashTable and call the function from this object?

Tags: c#

I created Class Disk

```
Disk disk1 = new Disk();

Hashtable myCatalog = new Hashtable();

try
{
    myCatalog.Add("Disk1", disk1);
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("An element with Key = \"Disk1\" already exists.");
}

Disk  valueColl = (Disk)myCatalog.Values;
        valueColl.
```

And here I have a problem.
How I can use this method ShowCompositions();

Comment: Sidenote: `Hashtable` dates from the earliest days of .NET.  There's almost certainly a better type to use now, perhaps `Dictionary<string, Disk>`.

Comment: myCatalog["Disk1"].ShowCompensation() ... or if you want all, use foreach on myCatalog.Values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Values` is a `ICollection` containing the values in the `Hashtable`.

You could do this.

```
Disk  valueColl = (Disk)myCatalog["Disk1"]; // access element with `Key`
valueColl.ShowCompositions(); // this will work
```

On other note as @jamesthorpe highlighted in comments , try using `Dictionary` over `Hashtable`, it has added advantages.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way

Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();

```
        foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in hashtable)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", entry.Key, entry.Value);
        }
```

Comment: Add value in hash table like hashtable[1] = "One";
            hashtable[2] = "Two";
            hashtable[13] = "Thirteen";